# Display an image in the admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I want to display an image in the admin grid of one of my modules.
I'm using the new grid system, the one with ui components.
I took a look at how the thumbnail is added in the grid for products, but it's kind of over my head.
My entity is not EAV, is a simple flat table entity.
I tried adding this in my ui component xml file

```
<column name="image">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/image</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

but it seams to have no effect on my grid. there is no image  (my db field is called image) column, no error, no nothing.
Can someone walk me through adding an image to the grid using ui components?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your ui component xml should have this added:

```
<column name="image" class="Your\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

..and then in Your\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail.php something similar to this:

```
<?php
namespace Your\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
    const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param Image $imageHelper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Image $imageHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $url = '';
                if($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ).'pathtoyourimage/'.$item[$fieldName];
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'your_module/yourentity/edit',
                    ['yourentity_id' => $item['yourentity_id']]
                );
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This helped me out! I had to change a couple of lines though. I changed `if($item[$fieldName] != '')` to `if($item['url'] != '')` and `'pathtoyourimage/'.$item[$fieldName]` to `'pathtoyourimage/'.$item['url']`. My `$fieldName` was returning 'image' however my db field was called 'url'. The rest of the `$item[$fieldName . '***']` were left in place.

Comment: Thanks, @MageDevNL. what if I'd want to show multiple images when we click on the thumbnail image.

Comment: perfect  its work good . Image shown ! But now i wnat to append some text with Image . I try but not usefulll .

Can you tell me how text append with image . i just want to show product image and in new line product sku and name

Comment: Perfect ! it work good !

how can we append some text with Image . 

I have show product image and now want to append sku and name on new line of image with same column . 
can you tell me how append some text with Image ?

Comment: @MageDevNL Can you please explain what is yourentity and yourentity_id ?

Answer (score 7):

In your grid.php define like below

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    array(
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'renderer'  => '\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\Image',
    )
);
```

Create `Image.php` under

> \Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\

and paste below code

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer;

class Image extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,      
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    }


    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $img;
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
           \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
       );
        if($this->_getValue($row)!=''):
            $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.$this->_getValue($row);
            $img='<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        else:
            $img='<img src="'.$mediaDirectory.'Modulename/no-img.jpg'.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        endif;
        return $img;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question right. My grid is build using UI-components. This does not work with UI-components.

Comment: this answer helped me to my work without using UI - components

Answer (score 4):

Just add this tag in you `ui_component` layout file

```
<column name="logo" class="NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Logo">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
            <!--<item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Brand Logo</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

and create this new file which we have assign in our `ui_component` column

```
<?php
namespace NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Logo extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const NAME = 'logo';

    const ALT_FIELD = 'name';

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,        
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {        
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
    * Prepare Data Source
    *
    * @param array $dataSource
    * @return array
    */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $mediaRelativePath=$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                $logoPath=$mediaRelativePath.$item['logo'];
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $logoPath;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item);
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'brand/manage/edit',
                    ['brand_id' => $item['brand_id'], 'store' => $this->context->getRequestParam('store')]
                );
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $logoPath;

            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return null|string
    */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

In `prepareDataSource` function you will get each column object.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is it possible to give height and width to thumbnail image..

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have solution for my question.
I have added a grid column with renderer block name as parameter.

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    array(
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'renderer'  => '\YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Inquiry\Grid\Renderer\Image',
    )
);
```

Then I have added created a renderer block as below:

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Inquiry\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\Object;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Image extends AbstractRenderer
{
    private $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
    /**
     * Renders grid column
     *
     * @param Object $row
     * @return  string
     */
    public function render(Object $row)
    {
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
        );
        $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.'/inquiry/images'.$this->_getValue($row);
        return '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="50"/>';
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: thanks for trying, but you did not pay attention while reading the question. I am trying to use the grid created via ui components not with a grid block as in magento 1.