# Magento 2. How to store media (images) and output to custom Data Grid View

Tags: magento2, admin, database, image, uicomponent

**In general**

I need a module, that works with custom in DB table.

It's main purpose is in providing data to a simple js script, that puts pins on the map.

**Question**

How to organise storing of images, that should appear above the pin.

[image]

**Assumptions**

I assume, that in DB we should store a link and an image — in some folder, designed for that. Also I assume, that Magento 2 has some classes to work organise this process.

**What do I have for now**

[image]

**Code**

Code examples are very dirty because of using a couple of another's examples. Main was [Ashsmith Blog](https://github.com/ashsmith/magento2-blog-module-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding additional `<column>` and additional *php class*.

Found an answer at:

[Display an image in the admin grid in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94321/display-an-image-in-the-admin-grid-in-magento-2?rq=1)