# How to get image path in magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, image

My image path is

> app/code/Vendor/Module/frontend/web/images/tool/test.png

How to get this image path?

Please see screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in which file you want to call this image?

Comment: I want to call the images on the grid in the admin
http://prntscr.com/ha6620
Please check this screen shot i have added.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94321/display-an-image-in-the-admin-grid-in-magento-2 try this link.

Answer (score 3):

You will get image by below code . I hope you have image name which you want there.

```
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
){
    $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
}

public function testImageUrl(){
    $url =  $this->assetRepo->getUrl("Namespace_Module::image.png");;
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: this url search for the image pub static which is not a way .

Comment: This is not working in recurringData.php file

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to show the thumbnail in admin grid please create the file Thumbnail.php in the the directory

> Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @param ContextInterface $context
 * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
 * @param Image $imageHelper
 * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param array $components
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    Image $imageHelper,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $url = '';
            if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ).$item[$fieldName];
            }
            $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
            $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
            $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                'module/item/edit',
                ['item_id' => $item['item_id']]
            );
            $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}

/**
 * @param array $row
 *
 * @return null|string
 */
protected function getAlt($row)
{
    $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
    return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
}
}
```

In you Ui Component Listing Create the column:

```
<column name="slider_image" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/tool/test.png');
```

Comment: this will not work on the admin grid section , Please see this screen shot and suggest a solution http://prntscr.com/ha6620

Comment: Are you using Ui Component or Grid.php for grid ?

Comment: Yes I am using UI component

Comment: Then you need to keep the images in pub/media folder and then follow this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94321/display-an-image-in-the-admin-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: above code work well on the frontend but i need to call the  images on the backend grid

Comment: The above code will call the image from **pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend** folder not from **pub/static/frontend** folder. That's why I am saying to keep the all files in pub/media folder and call using media url.

Answer (score 0):

Your ui component xml should have this added:

```
<column name="image" class="Your\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

> app/code/vendorname/Modulename/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Thumbnail.php

```
 something similar to this:

<?php
namespace Your\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
    const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param Image $imageHelper
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Image $imageHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $url = '';
                if($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ).'pathtoyourimage/'.$item[$fieldName];
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'your_module/yourentity/edit',
                    ['yourentity_id' => $item['yourentity_id']]
                );
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```