# How to set height and width for image in Adminhtml grids in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I added a custom image field to magento2 adminhtml grid by following code.

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'diagram',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'diagram',
        'label' => __('Diagram'),
        'title' => __('Diagram'),
        'required' => true, 
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'diagram',
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

It renders the image with height and width if 22 px. now how could I set height and width to the image.

Comment: try adding `'width' => '15px'`

Comment: I already tried this way. Its not working. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can customize your image by adding it using renderer

```
$fieldset->addType(
                'mycustomfield',
                '\Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\diagram'
            );

$fieldset->addField(
                'diagram',
                'mycustomfield',
                [
                    'name'  => 'diagram',
                    'label' => __('Diagram'),
                    'title' => __('Diagram')
                ]
            );
```

create a new block Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\diagram.php

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\Object;

class diagram extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{

public function getAfterElementHtml()
{
    $customDiv = '<label><span>Diagram</span></label><div id="customdiv"><img src="[Your Image Path]" width="150px" height="150px"></img></div>';
    return $customDiv;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure the implementation of **_getHeightWidth()** must be out side **_prepareForm()**

```
$fieldset->addField(
'diagram',
'image',
[
    'name' => 'diagram',
    'label' => __('Diagram'),
    'title' => __('Diagram'),
    'required' => true, 
    'header' => __('Image'),
    'index' => 'diagram',
    'disabled' => $isElementDisabled,
    'after_element_html' => $this->_getHeightWidth()

]
);

protected function _getHeightWidth()
{
   $html.='<script>;

   $(".diagram").css('height','15');
   $(".diagram").css('width','15');

   </script>';
   return $html;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but its not working for me

Comment: Can you share you block code??

Comment: https://gist.github.com/swathiramesh20/235e74ff4f854a283f2c4944eb55138f#file-main-php

Comment: is jQuery working on your page???

Comment: no. Its not working

Comment: You can resize the image after uploading and display in grid..

Comment: refer this link 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94321/display-an-image-in-the-admin-grid-in-magento-2

Comment: Please add `$html='';` in the `protected function _getHeightWidth()` method's first line.