# display image admin ui magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, image

[image]I have an issue with display image from admin UI component in magento 2.3.1.Who is solution  help me !
Here is my source:

```
<?php
    namespace Booking\Hotel\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    class Logo extends Column
    {
        const ALT_FIELD = 'title';
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
         */
        protected $imageHelper;
        /**
         * @param ContextInterface              $context
         * @param UiComponentFactory            $uiComponentFactory
         * @param StoreManagerInterface         $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
         * @param array                         $components
         * @param array                         $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            ContextInterface $context,
            UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
            array $components = [],
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
            parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }
        /**
         * Prepare Data Source
         *
         * @param array $dataSource
         * @return array
         */
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
        {
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                    $url = '';
                    if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                        if ($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                            $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                                ) . "catalog/tmp/category" . $item[$fieldName];
                        } else {
                            $url = $this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $url = $this->imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image');
                    }
                    $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                    $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                    $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
                }
            }
            return $dataSource;
        }
        protected function getAlt($row)
        {
            $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
            return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
        }
    }
```

This is the image column I added in the AAA file

```
<column name="hotel_image" class="Booking\Hotel\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Logo">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
        <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">title</item>
        <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
    </item>
</argument>
</column>
```

But it not show
[image]

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: @sikaku refer to this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95088/84221

Comment: I try show an Image  using UI Component in the admin Grid in Magento 2.3.1 but is not working !

Comment: check if you are getting value in $item in Logo.php

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94321/display-an-image-in-the-admin-grid-in-magento-2 Try this link hope this helps

Comment: i try but result still a top :(((